# Wagtail superuser unable to log in to CMS

Tags: django, admin, wagtail, superuser

I'm new to Wagtail and django. I've completed the https://learnwagtail.com/wagtail-for-beginners/ course and managed to get my site up and running on Digital ocean, however I'm unable to login to the admin area. I have tried using the superuser credentials that were used locally. I have also tried multiple times to create a new superuser with:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

and while the process appears to work successfully in the terminal (I'm logged in via SSH to my DO droplet), I continually receive the 'Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.' message when attempting to log in with the newly created username and password. If I use the shell to check users I can see my newly created user exists. I have also tried using

```
python manage.py changepassword myusername
```

to change the password on the previously created superusers, but again, while the process appears to work successfully in the terminal I continue to receive the error message when attempting to log in. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what I might be missing or doing wrong here? And / or how I might best debug the issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you serving the site?  NGINX?

Comment: @DanSwain yes nginx / gunicorn setup on a Digital Ocean droplet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to make sure my manage.py commands were picking up my production settings. So running:
`DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings.production ./manage.py createsuperuser`

and NOT:
`python manage.py createsuperuser` was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to set up a `Site` that matches the domain on which you're accessing your site.  In the command line, try this:

```
from wagtail.models import Site

s=Site.objects.last()
s.hostname='yourdomain'
s.site_name='verbose site name'
s.is_default_site=True
s.save()
```

If you don't already have a site in the database (or just want to add another one), then do `s=Site.objects.create()` instead of Site.objects.last()`place the three properties into the`create` statement as keywords.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't have a site created so followed these instructions, but it didn't solve my issue. I did find a solution though which I will add as an answer.